# Parameter length too long

Tags: java, string, command-line

I have a java program, and I need to pass to its main method a parameter that has a length of 8k characters. So when I try to execute this program passing that parameter, It just doesn't execute, but no error message is shown. How can I execute correctly that program?

Comment: Can you show the program? Also, how exactly you execute it? (from another method, from console, etc)

Comment: 8000 characters parameter? You should definitely fix the design of your program.

Comment: @Dorr To debug this would require seeing some code. And as Vlad points out, an 8k character parameter screams design issues

Comment: but the program is not even executed. I have a println("Start") as the first instruction in main, but it does not execute.

Comment: Is the program for a government project .

Comment: Are u starting application from cmd prompt.how it is possible to give 8k arg in cmd console.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible that your shell won't allow to exec a program having an argument list above the system limit.  Assuming can modify your java program, you should add an option to get the value of the parameter from a file rather than the command-line.

You can also write a wrapper that will invoke your `main`:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;

public class MyWrapper
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(args[0]);

        //assuming the data is the first argument
        args[0] = getStringFromReader(reader);

        //invoke real main
        MyClass.main(args);

    }

    public static String getStringFromReader(Reader reader) throws IOException
    {
        final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
        char[] buffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
        Reader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader, BUFFER_SIZE);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        int length = 0;
        while ((length = bufferedReader.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1)
        {
            stringBuffer.append(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        reader.close();

        return stringBuffer.toString();
    }
}
```

Then, you only need to call java like this:

`java MyWrapper my-file-containing-8k-data [other-args...]`

Comment: I can't modify the program in that way, I should get the value from command line.

Comment: The propose program is not a modification, it's an addition.  This is a trick not to have to modify your existing program.  You only need to compile it and to add it to your classpath along with your application jar.  The basic idea is "if you can call it from the command-line, you can call it from java code".

Comment: Under UNIX, you can also the following trick `java MyClass `cat my-file-containing-8k-data``

Comment: Is it not possible from command line? I can't read any file. It must come from command line.

Comment: It depends on your system.  What shell are you using?  I'm using TCSH on Linux and it let me type 8192 characters, no more.  The TCSH doc says that "the system limits argument lists to ARG_MAX characters", which is 131072 on my system (as defined in /usr/include/linux/limits.h).

Comment: The CMD.EXE limit is 8191 characters. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473/en-us

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to store this 8k parameter inside a file and pass the file name as a parameter. Then inside your main method you should open this file and read the 8k characters.